# How to make visual studio project inherit configuration setting for Intel Performance Libraries from a .props file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intel-mkl

I have a Visual Studio 2015 solution with multiple C++ projects inside it.

I am trying to make them share some build configurations.

Reading through tutorials, I figured the best way to do this is to create a .props file using Property Manager, and import it across the different projects.

The props file sets a property using the GUI configuration interface as so:
[Property.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNf8M.png)

The props file is at the top of the stack of props files (latest in evaluation)

The project that includes the props file is set to [inherit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfGBh.png) that configuration setting

However, when applied, it [doesn't take the value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHZg7.png) set in the props file, and builds without it, and crashes at runtime because this setting is missing.
It doesn't crash at runtime if I explicitly set that configuration to the desired value in the project properties itself.

Am I missing a step on how these .props files are to be used?

---

UPDATE:

Turns out this is problem is only happening with configurations for Intel performance Libraries (eg Use Intel MKL in linked pictures). All other configurations work as I expect them to